# python-telegram-bot принять-обработать-вернуть файл

Tags: python, telegram, бот, pdf, python-telegram-bot

ТОЛЬКО python-telegram-bot

Необходимо реализовать такую задачу:

Бот должен получить файл pdf, обработать его и вернуть отправителю и в заранее указанный канал телеграм.

Сама функция обработки готова, а вот принять файл и сохранить в нужную папку и потом вернуть, даже не знаю как.

Этот код получает команду /start и отдает сообщение, и вот после этого, нужно чтобы он получал файл от юзера.

```
async def start(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    await context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text="Отправь мне файл!")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    application = ApplicationBuilder().token('TOKEN').build()
    
    start_handler = CommandHandler('start', start)
    application.add_handler(start_handler)
```

Буду благодарен за любую помощь. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Для того чтобы бот мог принимать файлы от пользователей, вам нужно добавить соответствующий обработчик. В библиотеке python-telegram-bot для этого используется MessageHandler с фильтром Filters.document. Вот как можно модифицировать ваш код:

```
    from telegram.ext import MessageHandler, Filters
    from telegram import Update
    
    async def start(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
        await context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text="Отправь мне файл!")
    
    async def handle_document(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
        # Получаем объект файла из сообщения
        document = update.message.document
        
        # Сохраняем файл в нужную папку (замените 'path/to/save' на свой путь)
        file_path = context.bot.get_file(document.file_id).download('path/to/save/' + document.file_name)
        
        # Вызывайте вашу функцию обработки файла здесь, передавая путь к файлу
        # process_file(file_path)
    
        # Отправляем файл назад пользователю
        await update.message.reply_document(document.file_id)
    
        # Отправляем файл в заранее указанный канал (замените 'channel_id' на ID вашего канала)
        await context.bot.send_document(chat_id='channel_id', document=document.file_id)
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        application = ApplicationBuilder().token('TOKEN').build()
        
        start_handler = CommandHandler('start', start)
        document_handler = MessageHandler(Filters.document, handle_document)
    
        application.add_handler(start_handler)
        application.add_handler(document_handler)
```